# Binome-like sum with even integers

Tags: real-analysis, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to compute the following sum
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n C^{2k}_{2n} \frac{(2k)!}{k! 2^k} x^{2n - 2k} y^{2k}. $$
I don't have many ideas, I tried to play a little with the factorials, but it did not lead me anywhere. I am supposed to recognized something here ?

I should mention that my notation of binomial coefficient is
$ C^i_j = \frac{j!}{i! (j-i)!}$ hence $C^i_j = {j \choose i}$.

(P-s: It appears that I can not make a research on MSE this morning, for some reason only the asking question feature works. Hence, apologies if the question has been asked somewhere else.)

Comment: My notation is the other way around. I have edited the question accordingly. Thank you for pointing that.

Comment: This probably would not help, but taking $x=y=1$ and evaluating, the sums coincides with https://oeis.org/A066222, "bisection of https://oeis.org/A001189".

Comment: At least it gives me some intuition about the coefficients. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2 n}{2 k}\,\frac{ (2 k)! }{2^{k}\,k!}\,  x^{2 n-2 k}\,y^{2 k}$$
Let $x^2=2y^2\, z$ to make
$$S_n=2^n y^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2 n}{2 k}\,\frac{(2 k)! }{2^{2 k}\,k!} z^{n-k}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2 n}{2 k}\,\frac{(2 k)! }{2^{2 k}\,k!} z^{n-k}=(-1)^n\, U\left(-n,\frac{1}{2},-z\right)$$ where appears Tricomi's  confluent hypergeometric function